# Is there a way to determine the "starting point" of a job run?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I'm migrating a stream analytics job from Databricks/Spark to Azure Stream Analytics. Input is from IoTHub, and the query has to emit events every time when a sensor value changes between threshold ranges (e.g. from "warning" to "alert" range).

The existing solution utilizes "stateful streaming", i.e. it holds the last status per device in memory and compares on every new message. On job startup (or in some additional scenarios) there is no "last status"; in this case an additional event is created - and handled gracefully by downstream components.

I'm trying to implement this functionality in ASA:

1. Comparing with the last record can easily be done by using

```sql
lag(value, 1, null) over (partition by(serialMachine) limit duration(minute, 60))
```

2. When tested with local input data the result of the above is empty for the first record, which can be used to create a message.
3. But when run on Azure, "lag" returns a value, **even if the source record for it has a timestamp before the configured job start time**. I guess it's seen as "output start time", and all available or at least some more messages are loaded from IoTHub regardless of this timestamp.

I tried with functions ISFIRST and LAST, but all of these refer to a time window, i.e. derived conditions will be met periodically. But I only need it once.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The starting time of a job is actually defining the time of the first output. However Azure Stream Analytics will look back in the stream of events, in your case 60 minutes since you have a LAG with 60 minutes.
We recently added more info on this behavior on [the start job doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/start-job).
For your case, you can start a job 60 minutes later to not read any past info.

Let me know if you have any further question, I will be happy to help.

Thanks,

JS

Comment: Thanks, Jean-Sébastien, for the explanation. Choosing a start time 60 minutes later would cause 60 minutes without any output events, right? That wouldn't work for me (and I wonder if the lag wouldn't return a value in this case, too (as events from 60 minutes before start are always there). I searched for any information that could be used in a query to create a condition that's true exactly once per job run, e.g. job starting time, a time window counter, etc.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to harcode the query start time in the SQL (e.g. if time > X)  or in reference data. This is not ideal though.  Are you starting and stopping the job regularly?

Comment: Yes, I see, that would probably work (agree on "not ideal", too). The job won't be started regularly, but only if required (in case of the current solution i.e. when something went wrong in either creating or processing the calculated "status change" events). Thanks for your ideas. Should we try to create a topic on UserVoice for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, it looks like the source record has been adjusted. This means that the `System.Timestamp` (i.e. the actually considered timestamp) has been "moved" in the future, after the start time. Have you tried dropping late events? You can tune your policy in the `Configure -> Event Ordering` menu.

Reference: [Configuring event ordering policies for Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/event-ordering)

Comment: I believe it's not a problem of adjusted source records, but with the intended behaviour of ASA that @Jean-Sebastién described in his answer: to collect all events for the whole time windows that are used for aggregations in the query at startup, even if these have a timestamp before output start.

Comment: Yep, I agree :)